# About a group notation: $2.M_{12}$ and $M_{12}.2$, this latter also depicted as $M_{12}:2$.

Tags: group-theory, notation

For years, I have been studying group theory as an amateur, to lead to a better and deep comprehension of the Mathieu Groups and the Conway Groups. Recently, I came across a notation I've never seen explained explicitly in the many books I have about group theory.

Let's take $M_{12}$ for instance: on the ATLAS online about it I saw mentioned both $2.M_{12}$ and $M_{12}.2$, this latter also depicted as $M_{12}:2$.
What are the meaning of these notations? Of course $M_{12}$ is just a guess, I saw also $2.A_8$ and similar.
Thank for helping as always.

Comment: One is an extension of $C_2$ by $G$ and the other is an extension of $G$ by $C_2$. If only I could remember which is which....

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M12=), where the notation $M_{12}.2$ is "explained" (and also $S_6:2$ etc.)

Comment: @AnginaSeng Each is an extension of $G$ by $C_2$, depending on who you talk to. $2.G$ has a central esubgroup of order $2$.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde. Please, consider to promote your comments to a legitimate answer, so I could vote it.

Comment: There are some subtleties here. In $M_{12}:2$, the colon means that the extension is split, but we can still write $M_{12}.2$ for the same group, meaning that we don't know (or perhaps don't care) whether or not  it is split.  You can use a raised dot (which I write as \udot, which doesn't seem to work here) to say that the extension is definitely not split. Also note that there are two non-isomorphic groups with the structure $2.M_{12}:2$. Note that $A_5.2$ would normally only be used for the group $S_5$, since we would write $A_5 \times 2$ for the direct product.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt. Where can I find for a deep and clear explanation of extensions? As far as I can see $2.M_{12}$ is a group in which $M_{12}$ is normal. So, I guess that taking the quotient between the two, I would get a group isomorphic to $C_2$. Is that correct? If yes I was wondering if the process of extending a group is actually involving a direct, semi direct or wreath product. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you have it the wrong way round. $2.M_{12}$ is a group $G$ having centre $Z$ of order 2 with $G/Z \cong M_{12}$, whereas $M_{12}.2$ is a group having a normal subgroup of index $2$ isomorphic to  $M_{12}$. The notation is defined in the Atlas of Finite Groups.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt, I will have a look to it in my ATLAS copy,

Comment: OFF TOPIC @DerekHolt: I've recently bought your book about Computational Group Theory since, as a C++ developer with an addiction to Group Theory, I was curious to see how to do coset enumeration in the "real world". Your book is a great help and I use it as a companion to learn group theory with a language which is closer to the one I'm using in my every day job. Thanks for sharing it.